# Choleky decomposition using cholmod package

Tags: python, sparse-matrix, matrix-decomposition

I am trying to use the cholesky decomposition to invert a sparse matrix and I found this great package to help me on my problem.
My issue is that I keep getting `CholmodNotPositiveDefiniteError` although I verified with the eigenvalues that my matrix is positive and I tried adding small positive diagonal matrix but it didn't work. Here's my notebook

Could you please help me on this?

[image]

Comment: Just in case: are you sure that the matrix is symmetric? In numpy, `X * Y` means element-wise product, not matrix product; I suspect that it's not what intedned.

Comment: @Dmitry I don't think that's the case for sparse matrix , I've verified that it's equivalent to the X.T.dot(X)